# When will a "self." method/variable be recognized within a python script?

Tags: python, windows

I am having some trouble with a script I am writing and I have narrowed the problem down to the start_new_thread function is not executing the "self.handle" block.  I am having some difficulty understanding what I can replace there or how I can get this to recognize this method.  Can anyone please advise what I could use in place or explain to me why it is not seeing the "handle" method I have inserted into the class?

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import pythoncom
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
import sys
import optparse
import thread
import exceptions
import contextlib
import logging


class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "flaspsrv"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Flash Policy Server"
    _svc_description_ = "Initialize Flash Policy Server"

    def __init__(self,args):
        logging.basicConfig(filename='C:\\Uploads\\testing.log', level=logging.DEBUG, filemode='a', format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        try:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except AttributeError:
            # AttributeError catches Python built without IPv6
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except socket.error:
            # socket.error catches OS with IPv6 disabled
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            logging.info('Listening on port 843')
            self.sock.bind(('localhost', 843))
            self.sock.listen(5)

        try:
            while True:
                thread.start_new_thread(handle, self.sock.accept())
        except socket.error, e:
            logging.info('Error accepting connection: %s' % (e[1],))

    def handle(self, conn, addr):
        logging.info('Temp2')
        addrstr = '%s:%s' % (addr[0],addr[1])
        try:
            logging.info('Connection from %s' % (addrstr,))
            with contextlib.closing(conn):
                # It's possible that we won't get the entire request in
                # a single recv, but very unlikely.
                request = conn.recv(1024).strip()
                if request != '<policy-file-request/>\0':
                    logging.info('Unrecognized request from %s: %s' % (addrstr, request))
                    return
                logging.info('Valid request received from %s' % (addrstr,))
                fo = file('flashpolicy.xml', 'rb')
                conn.sendall(fo.read(10001))
                logging.info('Sent policy file to %s' % (addrstr,))
        except socket.error, e:
            logging.info('Error handling connection from %s: %s' % (addrstr, e[1]))
        except Exception, e:
            logging.info('Error handling connection from %s: %s' % (addrstr, e[1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Comment: You really should quote the exact error message.  Lacking that:    thread.start_new_thread( __self.__ handle, self.sock.accept()) ?

Comment: There is no error message John-- it compiles and executes, creates a service and runs, the service just "STOPS" when I attempt to make a connection, since I have a working version of this using the same code I figured it had to be to do with the handle method and when I am in my Python editor thing i noticed self.handle does not pop up in the version i am having problems with.  I have absolutely no background in python prior to this script, i'm just trying to apply remnants of knowledge from other code.  Sorry if I wasn't the best at describing the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has no implicit `this` - which is why you need to explicitely have to declare the current instance (`self`) as the first argument for method functions (no that's not a typo), and why you have to explicitely use it for any access to an attribute or method (which are attributes too).

To make a long story short, you need to pass `self.handle`, not `handle`.

Comment: I have tried this with self.handle and the behavior is the same.  The comment "Temp2" in the very beginning of the handle method never prints to the log file, but I can see port 843 is open on netstat etc, so everything up until that point seems to be okay.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question asked in the title, a `self.` method/variable `foo` will be recognized when:

1. `self` is a variable in the current scope that references an object with the appropriate member, and
2. you actually use `self.foo` to reference `foo`.

That is to say, `self` is not a keyword in Python; its usage is merely a convention, and the interpreter has no knowledge of its special (conventional) meaning, which is as a replacement for the `this` keyword in other languages. (In fact, some Python programmers eschew `self` and use other variable names, such as `s`.)

The real point, though, is that whatever variable name you assign to it, the *receiver* of a python method must always be explicitly specified, even inside the lexical scope of a method in the same class. This is because the interpreter treats the `object.member(args)` syntax essentially as syntactic sugar for `Class.member(object,args)` (try it and see!); in other words, an object method is not given any special knowledge of the class it's part of, and must explicitly use the receiver (`self`) every time it accesses the object it's manipulating--even though, in a sense, the method is *part of* that object.

Comment: Actually the `method` _do_ know which class and instance it belongs to. It's the `function` that don't. cf https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod for more on this.